# How can I adjust user form tabs in a tab strip, triggered by Textbox input?

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I'm missing some basic concepts and I don't know what they are. I'm getting a Compile Error "invalid use of property" when I use my user form to update tab strips. I'm trying to trigger an update to the Tab strip that responds to valid integer numbers entered into the Text box. Below is my current code.

I'm also don't know how to check the count in the Tab index and then add to the count help on this would also be appreciated.

Another Error I get is when a number value is checked by the IsValid Function it asks about a Debug when a Character is entered. Am I checking the input incorrectly?

The image below shows the form layers. Where Test1 is a Frame (on Userform page), TabStrip is located within the same frame as the Text Box (referenced in the code as TStrip1).

```
Function IsValid(numIn As Integer) As Boolean

   IsValid = (numIn Like [1-15])

End Function

Private Sub TextBox11_Change()

    Dim ValidNum As Integer

    ValidNum = TextBox11
    Call IsValid(ValidNum)
    Dim x As Integer

    x = TextBox11
    Call TStrip1(x)

End Sub

Private Function TStrip1_(ByRef,ByVal TStrip1) As Integer

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim TabNum As Integer

    TabNum = x

    UserForm1.TStrip1.TabIndex.Add = TabNum

End Function

Private Sub TStrip1_Change()

End Sub
```

[image: Single Form Tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'Invalid use of property' error is caused by:

```
Private Function TStrip1_(ByRef,ByVal TStrip1) As Integer
```

You specified ByRef AND ByVal for the argument. Changing that line to:

```
Private Function TStrip1_(TStrip1) As Integer
```

should remove that error.

I would, however, rewrite your code like so:

```
Option Explicit 'always use option explicit (just do)


Private Function IsValid(numIn As Variant) As Boolean
Dim n As Long

n = Val(numIn) 'cast to long

'check if n is between 1 and 15:
If n > 0 And n < 16 Then
    IsValid = True
Else
    IsValid = False
End If

End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim ValidNum As Long

If IsValid(Me.TextBox1.Value) Then
    ValidNum = Val(Me.TextBox1.Value)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
Call AdjTabs(ValidNum)

End Sub
Private Sub AdjTabs(n As Long)
Dim i As Long

If Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Count = n Then
    Exit Sub
ElseIf Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Count < n Then
    For i = Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Count To n - 1
        Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Add
    Next i
Else
    For i = Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Count To n + 1 Step -1
        Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Remove (Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Count - 1)
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

only thing left is to change the tabs names, but that's up to you now. I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: That seemed to get tabs functioning exactly how I wanted. Now to tinker with the names. I think I see the concept I was missing I got the syntax for the functions wrong. When declaring tabs I used integer, but needed to use variant and long because 15 is considered long? I didn't realize that when declaring a function you declare a variable that will be assigned a value when the function is called,is that right? On another note should I be storing my 'function subs' in the class module section of my VBA project?

Comment: No, 15 is not long. Technically, it's an integer. Integers can store values up to 255. But underneath, excel converts those integers to long values anyway, so there is no real advantage to use integers. I used a variant as an argument, but a string would suffice. Textbox.value is always a string value. I am used to storing as all my code in codemodules, except when it is absolutely nessesary to do otherwise. In this case, the most logical place to store the functions is in the userform. Those are functions that are specific for this userform and it is unlikely that you would use then anywhere

Comment: I meant, use them anywhere else in your project.